# Confirm HTTP Request Sent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I am using the $http get from Angular, I want to confirm that a http request is sent to our API. I am aware of the .success method but this waits for a return, is there a way to just get the $http object to confirm the request has been sent?

Comment: Why would it not get sent?  Is it just that you don't trust Angular - or do you have a more specific scenario in mind?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way for JavaScript in a browser to detect whether a request has been sent without getting a response.

Comment: @JamesGaunt thanks for the response. a bit of both, it is critical for me that a request is sent and therefore need to know if angular for what ever reason doesn't send the request or it is interrupted whilst making it so I can handle it. does that make sense?

Comment: @JohnDoe - not really no :) how can it be critical that it is sent, but not critical that it is received?  It sounds like you need the server to confirm the receipt?  The only way to do this is for the server to send a message back (AKA a response).

Comment: @JamesGaunt I think I will have to do this, the request calls a function on my backend which I know will complete if requested but it takes a while to complete therefore I did not want the user to wait, therefore I wanted to just get a successful receipt of the request rather than waiting for a response!

Comment: In that case maybe you could respond immediately and schedule the action for future processing, or on some server frameworks you can do work after the response is sent.

Comment: *In addition* to confirming via the succss function, it sounds like one thing you may want is to put the http.get inside of a try { } catch(ex) {} block; If some bad parameter to angular causes the request not to send, then you will be able to report that case there, or maybe try it again (but if a parameter is bad, chances are you won't be able to auto-resend). Of course, this sounds pointless anyway because if the get() method fails, the next JS line won't run, and the success function definitely won't run (so you have your answer).

Answer (score 0):

I used something similar to track number of requests sent, which are waiting for response.

Add an http-interceptor on app level:

```
.config(['$httpProvider',
    function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('RequestCounterInterceptor');
    }
])
```

The code of interceptor (you can modify it to handle just requests to your API's url):

```
.factory('RequestCounterInterceptor', ['RequestCounterService', '$q',
    function(RequestCounterService, $q) {
        return {
            'request': function(request) {
                RequestCounterService.increase();
                return request;
            },
            'requestError': function(request) {
                RequestCounterService.increase();
                return $q.reject(request);
            },
            'response': function(response) {
                RequestCounterService.decrease();
                return response;
            },
            'responseError': function(response) {
                RequestCounterService.decrease();
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
    }
])
```

The service:

```
.service('RequestCounterService', ['$log',
    function($log) {
        var currentRequestCount = 0; // init
        return {
            increase: function() {
                currentRequestCount++;
                $log.log("currentRequestCount ", currentRequestCount);
            },
            decrease: function() {
                currentRequestCount--;
                $log.log("currentRequestCount ", currentRequestCount);
            },
            getCount: function() {
                return currentRequestCount;
            }
        };
    }
])
```

Then anywhere in you controller, directive... you can use `RequestCounterService.getCount()` to see how many requests have been sent and did not received response yet. You could display a message to user like `There are currently XY requests being processed by the server` or similar.

But in case the processing takes too much time, you should solve your issue server-side as James Gaunt proposed in comments.